# Map a user to a login without recreating the user

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to create a new server login. Then I need to map this login to many (existing) database users.

The only way I found to accomplish this is by dropping the database users and creating them again with the "FOR LOGIN" option.

I'm wondering if there is any other way I could map a user to a new login without dropping and recreating the user.

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation for `ALTER USER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060(SQL.110).aspx)? As long as the user is currently mapped to a different login, you can change that mapping using: `ALTER USER username WITH LOGIN = correct_login;`

Answer (score -3):

Here are some of your options to do User related stuff with TSQL:

Change default database of a login:

```
alter login <loginname> with default_database = <dbname>;
```

Create a user in a database for a given login:

```
use <dbname>;
create user <username> from login <loginname>;
```

Make an user member of db_owner group:

```
use <dbname>
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', '<username>';
```

Make a login 'dbo' of a database:

```
alter authorization on database::<dbname> to <loginname>;
```

Comment: doesn't answer the question.